# Is there a function for toggling a div on page load without a button press?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I'm trying to toggle a div on page load based on a variable. The code I'm using was made by someone else, and I'm pulling the variable from a database.

I've tried many different jquery toggle options but none of them seem to be working.

```
<%

 If (FIELD_VALUE("GRADE").Value) = "1" Then Response.Write"<script type='text/javascript'>$('#accordion7').show();</script>": Response.Write""

 %>
```

I'm looking to show a hidden div based on the grade, but right now it just stays hidden regardless of what I try.

Comment: Do you know about window.onload ???

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to show a div based on a variables value at page load, you can totally run the code below. I have just used a text element to show the effect, but you can easily replace that with a div and select it by id. For more information on this please take a look at: [jQuery select by ID](https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/)

```js
var grade = 1;

$(document).ready(function() {
    if(grade == 1) {
      $("p").show();
    }else {
      $("p").hide();
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="your_id">Text</p>
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! The document ready function is on the right track, but the problem I'm having is meshing ASP NET with Javascript. The variable can't be set to something static, it changes based on the user that logs in. So right now I have this:      $(document).ready(function() {
    If (FIELD_VALUE("GRADE").Value) = "1"
    {
      $("#accordion7").show();
    }else {
      $("#accordion7").hide();
    }
}); Unfortunately this doesn't work, as the div stays hidden (and using that ajax jquery library breaks my accordions somehow!)

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the original code worked, but only if it was placed after the corresponding accordion in the code.

---

```
<% If (FIELD_VALUE("GRADE").Value) = "1" 
Then Response.Write"
<script type='text/javascript'>$('#accordion7').show();</script>": Response.Write"" %>
```